# How to upload a non standard Python library in AWS Glue?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nltk, aws-glue, egg

I'm trying to install praw and nltk libraries into a python shell within AWS Glue 1.0 but can't seem to figure out how to make it work.

For example for praw, I have tried adding '--additional-python-modules' in the job parameters of the job details and the value being 'praw==7.6.1' but it does not seem to work.

Doing further research online, I saw something about zipping the library .whl files into an .egg which I then should upload into Glue but I don't know if would work but also don't know how to create an .egg file with non standard libraries as dependencies.

Any help in sorting out this issue would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this small article: [external-python-libraries-aws-glue-job](https://helicaltech.com/external-python-libraries-aws-glue-job/)